# How safe is to have a LinkedIn account where you have published all the important information about yourself?

Tags: social-engineering

How safe is it to make your information public? I know that there are many risks from social engineers' side, if you put everything about yourself a hacker will have most of the information about you which you gave them by yourself like people do all the time on Facebook or any other social media.

I wonder how do cyber security experts and those kind of people prevent it and keep themselves safe? is it just an own risk issue?

Comment: No matter if you have your profile on a private or a public mode, when you put your information on the Internet (for my example, on LinkedIn), you're always at risk, because if a bad guy decides to hack you he'll have too much information about you from just a single LinkedIn account.

Answer (score 3):

The concept you are looking for is "digital footprint" and it goes far beyond any one social network.

Any information that is public can be used against you. You have to make an assessment about the risk/reward of making data public, and once it is public, you have to treat anyone using that information as public, too. Too often people think that if someone knows something about them, then they can be trusted, an "insider".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're right, everyone needs to assess all the risks and rewards and then decide whether it's worth to create a LinkedIn account or not.